# How do I add dependencies to gradle.build

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on Android Studio and my activities include `ViewPager`s. For that I had to install packages (Android Support Repository and Android Support Library). Now that I have already installed these, I opened *gradle.build* and this is what I see:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

### My question:

What should I add and where should I add it in here?

Also, I cant locate SDK in my computer :/ . A little help would be really appreciated.

Comment: A bit offtopic, but really usefull tool: http://gradleplease.appspot.com/

Answer (score 3):

Android use multi project build setup. Your existing file is MAIN build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        // this is where you need to put dependencies of your BUILD SCRIPT
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
      compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.1'
      compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.1'
      // This is where you put dependencies EVERYONE of your modules need.
    }


}
```

In the sub directories of your main build.gradle resides individual build.gradle files.

Module A

```
    dependencies {
      // This is where you put dependencies, your module need.
    }
```

Module B

```
    dependencies {
      // This is where you put dependencies, your module need.
    }
```

Comment: From your answer, I get the place where i should be making the changes. From the official website, i see that i have to add this:    dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
} Am i correct? This is it? After that i should be able to work with viewpager? Thanks

Comment: This is what my gradle.build looks now:                   allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    } and when i switch to my java file, it still says that cant resolve symbol support

Comment: I cant but if there is a document on how to through command line, i can follow that

Comment: in the directory of your main build.gradle try executing gradle command

Comment: Your android studio project contains gradlew. According to your OS, try to execute gradlew.bash or gradlew.sh in the build.gradle directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one gradle files. one of them is located in your project directory. Same name (build.gradle). find it and put your dependencies there.

To find your SDK path: File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location. (Android Studio v0.8.14)

Comment: here is what i did 1. I installed anroid support library and android support repository. 2. I opened build.gradle( with the project name written in brackets) and then i added     dependencies {

        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0"
    } under allprojects below jecntre. 3. Now, gradle wants to sync and when i sync, i get an error messages that Gradle DSL method not found  compile(). In my java file, when i add import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;, it still says that it doesnt reolve symbol "support"

Comment: I found out that sdk location for android studio is not in c>users>android studio but its in c>android>sdk ( This sdk package was installed along with eclipse i think because i see thatin adt_bundle folder, SDK folder sits right next to eclipse folder. I am really starting to doubt if i have configured android studio correctly. Please help